# Maintaning Gridview header when changing page index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

As my question implies :)

I have a gridview that was datasourced and Databinded on a list<> of a class
Each time I change the page of my grid..the header is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can add the header in the "RowCreated" handler of GridView.